# How to convert date time to epoch up to day only

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
const myTime = Date.now()

console.log(myTime) // 1659622334878
```

Now when I use it like this

```
console.log(new Date(myTime).toUTCString())
```

I get `"Thu, 04 Aug 2022 14:12:14 GMT"`

How do I format `myTime (1659622334878)` so that time of the day doesn't affect the output.

Expected output `"Thu, 04 Aug 2022 00:00:00 GMT"`

Comment: round down to nearest 86,400,000 milliseconds (there are 86,400 seconds in a day) - `new Date(Date.now() - (Date.now() % 86_400_000)).toUTCString()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To truncate the date to midnight UTC, try [`Date.prototype.setUTCHours()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setUTCHours):

```js
const myTime = new Date();
myTime.setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
console.log(myTime.toUTCString());
```

Comment: I added a link to the docs for the method that you used, put your code in a snippet, and gave an upvote. Nice job using a built-in API which solves this exact problem.

Comment: Agreed, that looks nicer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Created using Date.now(), which returns milliseconds
const myTime = 1659622334878;

// Time constants in milliseconds
const SECOND = 1e3;
const MINUTE = SECOND * 60;
const HOUR = MINUTE * 60;
const DAY = HOUR * 24; // or 8.64e7 or 86_400_000

const myDayAtMidnight = Math.floor(myTime / DAY) * DAY;
// Order of ops:             2            1      3

// 1. Divide by milliseconds in one day to get floating point days
// 2. Remove the remainder
// 3. Multiply by milliseconds in one day to get back to milliseconds

console.log('My day:', new Date(myDayAtMidnight).toUTCString());
console.log('My day with time:', new Date(myTime).toUTCString());
```

You can, of course, precalculate these dynamically-calculated constants and inline the value for `DAY` in your own code, but they're there to provide context for the thought process of solving this problem using the approach of math unit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a string so `slice()` and `.concat()`

```js
let d = new Date(Date.now()).toUTCString();
console.log(d.slice(0, 17).concat('00:00:00 GMT'));
```

Comment: I don't like that the result is hard to reuse in a subsequent transformation, but as an end-of-data-flow op, this is surgical.

Comment: The result is a string which is properly formatted. It works for any date since the index of characters doesn't change in the UTC format of Www, dd Mmm yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT. The result is the same as the accepted answer a string, it is kind of obvious with the name of .toUTC **String** ()

Comment: Of course, but another kind of transformative date operation (e.g. "add 26 days") will be much more difficult to perform with string manipulation. That's why I said end-of-data-flow (just before presentation).

Comment: *"Expected output "Thu, 04 Aug 2022 00:00:00 GMT"* is verbatim. Even though the accepted answer is far more elegant than mine, the result is exactly the same. I understand your point, and I would consider that concerning my answer had the question required what you are saying.

Comment: I hope my [initial comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73237706/how-to-convert-date-time-to-epoch-up-to-day-only/73238123?noredirect=1#comment129343866_73238123) wasn’t misinterpreted: it was ultimately a compliment regarding your approach: string manipulation is not something I tend to reach for when manipulating dates, and it fit the requirements exactly (ergo “surgical”). Also, I don’t see an accepted answer yet…

Comment: Ha! I liked the other question so much I must've accepted it in my brain! I upvoted it and yours too, which are both better than my own.

Answer (score 0):

Given that there are 86,400 seconds in a day (24 × 60 × 60)  you can round the result of `Date.now()` down to the nearest 86,400,000 milliseconds

```js
let now = Date.now();
let date = new Date(now - (now % 86_400_000));
console.log(date.toUTCString());
```

*No idea why I know off the top of my head that there are 86,400 seconds or 1,440 minutes in 24 hours.*